# Auto link function not working properly

Tags: php, regex, autolink

I created a PHP function that will automatically turn URLs into links, link Twitter `@reply` usernames to its Twitter profile, and turn email addresses into links with the `mailto` protocol.

Here is the script:

```
function autolink($a, $b){
        $e = "";
        $f = array(
            'link' => '~(http(s|)\:\/\/(www\.|)((\w+)\.(\w+)(\:[0-9]{2,5}|)\.[a-z]{2,5}|(\w+)(\:[0-9]{2,5}|)\.[a-z]{2,5}))((((\/|)\w+)(\.[a-z]{2,5}|))+)(\?(\w+\=\w+(\&|))+|)~',
            'email' => '~\w+\@\w+(\:[0-9]{2,5}|)\.[a-z]{2,5}~',
            'twitter' => '~\@([a-zA-Z_0-9]){1,15}~'
        );
    switch ($b) {
    case "link":$e = preg_replace_callback($f['link'], function ($a) {return '<a href="'.$a.'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">'.$a.'</a>';},$a);break;
    case "email":$e = preg_replace_callback($f['email'], function ($a) {return '<a href="mailto:'.$a.'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">'.$a.'</a>';},$a);break;
    case "twitter":$e = preg_replace_callback($f['twitter'], function ($a) {return '<a href="https://twitter.com/#!/'.str_replace('@','',$a).'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">'.$a.'</a>';},$a);break;
    }
    return $e;
}
```

The only issue I'm having is that instead of returning the link it returns the word: "Array".

For example, this:

```
autolink("This is my site http://weebuild.biz", "link");
```

Is returning this:

> This is my site Array

When it should be returning this:

> This is my site `<a href="http://weebuild.biz"  rel="nofollow"
>   target="_blank">http://weebuild.biz</a>`

The original script was in JavaSript which I wrote as well: http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/umgqR/2/

Since I'm not a PHP developer the JavaScript version has some more features.

Maybe the issue is that I took the regular expression from JavaScript and just put it in the PHP. I'm not sure if regular expressions in PHP are different from JavaScript.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following change:

```
case "link":$e = preg_replace_callback(
        $f['link'],
        function ($a) {
            return '<a href="'.$a[0].'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">'.$a[0].'</a>';
        },
        $a
     );
     break;
```

The issue is that the argument to the callback will be an array, not a string.

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

> A callback that will be called and passed an array of matched elements
>   in the subject string. The callback should return the replacement
>   string.

Comment: Thanks you ill just try changing all of the $a to $a[0]. Which seems like the only change

Comment: That is right, just the `$a` => `$a[0]`.  I just formatted the answer to be more readable.

Answer (score 2):

The `$a` inside of the callback is an array and returns something like this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => http://weebuild.biz
  [1] => http://weebuild.bi
  [2] => 
  [3] => 
  [4] => weebuild.bi
  [5] => 
  [6] => 
  [7] => 
  [8] => weebuild
  [9] => 
  [10] => z
  [11] => z
  [12] => z
  [13] => 
  [14] => 
  [15] =>
```

)

You might want to refer to `$a[0]` instead of just `$a`. Of course you need to do some checks to make sure there's that value and avoid any unexpected errors when referring to it.

Comment: Oh I see. Well i'm not really a PHP developer so i'm used to the JavaScript way which doesnt return an Array.